# My simple registration servlet in not running.don't know where it is going wrong . database is mysql and it is netbean IDE 8.0.2

Tags: html, servlets

**login.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    <html>    <head>     <title>Register-login-form Website</title>     <link href="style.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">          <script type="application/x-javascript"> addEventListener("load", function() { setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0); }, false); function hideURLbar(){ window.scrollTo(0,1); } </script>    <!--webfonts-->        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster|Pacifico:400,700,300|Roboto:400,100,100italic,300,300italic,400italic,500italic,500' ' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>     <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,100,500,600,700,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>    <!--webfonts-->    </head>    <body><!--start-login-form-->    <div class="main">    <div class="login-head">    <h1>Elegant Login  and Register forms</h1>    </div>    <div  class="wrap">     <div class="Regisration">    <div class="Regisration-head">
                                <h2><span></span>Register</h2>
                             </div>
                                                      <form action="LoginDataBase" method="get">
                                <input type="text" value="FirstName" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value === '') {this.value = 'FirstName';}" >
                                <input type="text" value="LastName" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value ==='') {this.value = 'LastName';}" >
                                <input type="text" value="EmailAddress" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value === '') {this.value = 'EmailAddress';}" >
                                <input type="text" value="UserName" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value ==='') {this.value = 'UserName';}" >
                                                                <input type="password" value="password" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value === '') {this.value = 'password';}" >
                                                               <!-- <input type="password" value="confirm password" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'confirm password';}" >-->

                                <!--<div class="Remember-me">
                                <!--<div class="p-container">
                                <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" ><i></i>I agree to the Terms and Conditions</label>
                                <div class ="clear"></div>-->


                                <div class="submit">
                                    <input type="submit" value="Sign Me Up >" />
                                </div>

                                                      </form>

                                </div>


                    </div>
                    <div class="Login">
                            <div class="Login-head">
                                <h3>LOGIN</h3>
                            </div>

                                            <form action="Checking" method="get">
                                <div class="ticker">
                                    <h4>Username</h4>
                                    <input type="text" value="reena_kandari" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'reena_kandari';}" ><span> </span>
                                    <div class="clear"> </div>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                <h4>Password</h4>
                                <input type="password" value="Password" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Password';}" >
                                            <div class="clear"> </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="checkbox-grid">
                                    <div class="inline-group green">
                                    <label class="radio"><input type="radio" name="radio-inline"><i> </i>Remember me</label>
                                    <div class="clear"> </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>

                                <div class="submit-button">
                                    <input type="submit" value="LOGIN  >" >
                                </div>
                                    <div class="clear"> </div>
                                            </form>
                                </div>


                    </div>
            </div>
                <!--//End-login-form--> 


    </body>
</html>
```

**LoginDataBase.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;  import java.io.PrintWriter;  import  java.sql.Connection;  import java.sql.DriverManager;  import java.sql.PreparedStatement;  import java.sql.SQLException;  import javax.servlet.ServletException;  import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;  @WebServlet(name="LoginDataBase",urlPatterns={"/LoginDataBase"})  public class LoginDataBase extends HttpServlet {
 @Override
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try(PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {String f=request.getParameter("FirstName");
        String l=request.getParameter("LastName");
        String e=request.getParameter("EmailAddress");
        String u=request.getParameter("UserName");
        String p=request.getParameter("password");
        try{Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shopping","root","mysql1234");
        PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into shopping values(?,?,?,?,?)");
        ps.setString(1,f);
        ps.setString(2,l);
        ps.setString(3,e);
        ps.setString(4,u);
        ps.setString(4,p);
        int i=ps.executeUpdate();
        if(i>0)
            out.print(" CONGRATULATIONS!...you are successfully registered....");}
        catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e2){
            System.out.print(e2);
        }
        }  }  }
```

Comment: Hi Reena, Explain what is the error coming when you run this program. Last part of your HTML page is out of form like username, password text box.

Comment: When i submit the data it shows nothing in the output page.

Comment: you are using username, password textbox, that is out of form. Add complete this div within form. Without adding in form, i don't think, you will be able to get in servlet. You need to first check, is your request is going to server or not.

Comment: Sorry but username and password is within the form.

Comment: I have posted answers in which i specified some reason why your code is not running. I hope, it will work now surely. if still you get any error then tell me, I will solve it out.

Comment: Sorry sir but again it's not running.data is coming from client side but it is not going to save and i have also added name attribute.

Comment: You have to check which exception is coming. I think there is some mistake while loading driver in servlet code and check table is available in your database or not. It's working properly in my system.

Comment: If still you are stuck in your application, then send me complete application on my mail id punitkumarchawla@gmail.com. I will sort it out surely.

Comment: Sir i am not able to understand what exactly i will send you?

Answer (score 1):

Below are the some reasons - why your code is not running

1. You haven't added name attribute in any of input type tag. Without adding name attribute, you can't get it's value in servlet. It will show you null. As we use id to give a unique identification for using in JavaScript or Jquery, same as we use name attribute to get its value in servlet or server side.

Ex. - 
Wrong

```
<input type="text" value="FirstName" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value === '') {this.value = 'FirstName';}" >
```

It should be look like this. 
Correct

```
<input type="text" value="FirstName" name="FirstName" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value === '') {this.value = 'FirstName';}" >
```

2. Check you are specifying correct servlet name where it will go when click on "SignmeUp" button. Just print

3. First check all values either it's coming from client side or not by printing in console by using System.out.println(); If all the values are coming properly and table is available in Database then data will be saved successfully. If still your data doesn't save then it will show you exception.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some little mistake .
you do not have name attribute in any input tag , but you can access this value in servlet by request.getParameter("FirstName") .

you correct the all html code like

and so on .

I hope your program is running successfully .